# editing postgresql.conf file on postgreSQL 9.2?

Tags: configuration, windows-7-x64, postgresql-9.2

I want to edit postgresql.conf file but when I tried to open it ,I can't how can I edit this file to change the value of listen_addresses parameter?

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error?  If so, please post more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have access to this file. On linux, being root or sudoer do the trick.
Don't forget to restart your database.